# iOS Simulator does not refresh correctly

Tags: ios, xcode, button, simulator

I try to simulate a very very simple application which I have created in Xcode 9. I try to simulate it in the iOS Simulator in an iPhone6 with iOS 11.2. I have also tested other devices with the same result.

On a real device, the app works as expected. But on the simulator it doesn't.

I expect, that the button will become orange after I have clicked on it. and the emoji should disappear. Instead it changes into some strange "shadowed" look. If I wait then, the button will sometimes turn its background to orange after around 30 seconds.

I have recorded a gif, to illustrate the problem.

http://www.giphy.com/gifs/l4pSUuBtN7aBVvbVe

**UPDATE:**

Here is another GIF: http://www.giphy.com/gifs/26DNe5B0vxIO6pHiw
The button gets refreshed, as soon as i drag down the info center.

Development machine: Mac mini 2011, i5, SSD, 8GB RAM, high Sierra

hope someone can help me.

**UPDATE: 15.02.18**
The problem only appears with iOS versions beginning from 10 and up. 
With iOS Version 9.0 there is no problem. Expect that there arent any emojis...

In the meantime, i have filed a bug report to apple. But i think there will be no response on that.

Looks that others having the same problem: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/96511

Comment: did you find any solution ? I have MacBook Pro 2011 and I have the similar issue from 3 month

Comment: Apple has confirmed that they have a bug with the Intel3000 HD GPU. There are several Bug reports open on their platform about that. I have also filed a bug report. They have combined all of the into one. I think the priority to solve this bug is extremly low. Unfortunatley!! I have stopped the development of apps. I dont want to buy a new mac just because they have a software bug!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**iOS 13 UPDATE: Use the `Hardware > Toggle In-call Status Bar` option for all devices with iOS 13 or higher. The activity indicator is gone for all devices. Fortunately, the in-call status bar no longer changes the layout size.**

--

I have finally found a working workaround for this!

For simulators without the notch, set this when you launch the app:

`[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;`

Swift 4.1:

```
UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
```

and never set it back to `NO`. This will show the little loading indicator in statusbar, which will keep the simulator constantly active and will solve your issue.

Just don't forget to make sure you will **not use it in the production configuration**.

Simulators with the notch in the status bar (iPhone X) don't show the activity indicator, but you can use Hardware > Toggle In-call Status Bar, because the in-call icon is animating and will also keep the screen active.

Comment: Dear David. You made my day!!!! This works how it should.
Just for others, finding this. Add these line of code in swift: 
UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true

Answer (score 1):

Found a workaround here (after looking at your link to Apple forum):
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/88446

In Terminal:

- If you have a discrete GPU in the system (eg: MBP 15" with Radeon HD 6750M):

  ```
  defaults write com.apple.CoreSimulator.IndigoFramebufferServices FramebufferPerformanceHint 2
  ```
- If you do NOT have a discrete GPU in the system (eg: MBP 13" or MacMini)

  ```
  defaults write com.apple.CoreSimulator.IndigoFramebufferServices FramebufferEmulationHint 1
  ```

To be sure, try both options. First option helped me (although I have MBP 13" Early 2011).

Comment: I have tried both workarounds. Unfortunatley they didnt worked for me.

Comment: @C.Hediger Simulator should be relaunched after changing defaults. Did you relaunch simulator after each option?  
P.S. I have updated my system to 10.13.5 since last time, and on the new system a second option (FramebufferEmulationHint 1) helped me, not first (FramebufferPerformanceHint 2) as on 10.12.6, on the same hardware. So I think some playing with these options may be needed, including relaunching simulator after each setting, reversing back an option or probably even relaunching Xcode or re-logging/restarting system.

Comment: I have tried both options without success. Apple has updated their Bug Case. They wrote thate there is still no solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem of simulator not updating the changes from database.
You might have problem with caches, the **simulators might need resetting.**

Try quitting iPhone Simulator, then run xcrun in Terminal:

```
xcrun simctl erase all
```