# iOS Swift Update to UI delayed

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, swift4

I have a subclass of UIView. In this class I would like to change the background when a specific boolean flag is changed. (I control this flag by `touchesBegan`)

Below is my code.

```
class TileView: UIView {

    let selectedBackgroundColor: UIColor = .cyan
    let nonSelectedBackgroundColor: UIColor = .white

    private var isSelected = false {
        didSet {
            backgroundColor = isSelected ? self.selectedBackgroundColor : self.nonSelectedBackgroundColor
            print("isSelected: " + String(isSelected))
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
       isSelected = !isSelected
    }
}
```

When `touchesBegan` is fired I get `isSelected: true` in the console but the background color does not change.

I've noticed that after tapping in the view, if I tap somewhere else on the screen outside of the view it changes color.

I'm stumped on what could be causing this.

EDIT:

Here is a short recording of the behavoir in cause my description is not clear enough.
Each white square in the recording is a TileView.
https://gyazo.com/e8152d18b4efe1c5b1c6c04b55b661fe

Comment: it a simple use case of  `let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTap(_:)))
TileView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)` and implement the handler like this `@objc func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
    // handling code
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I discovered that my code is fine, the problem is acutally the simulator was not updating properly.
Refer to the answer here for more details.

[iOS Simulator does not refresh correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48773526/ios-simulator-does-not-refresh-correctly)